# Do action in iFRame when people click in a specific part

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have an iframe with 3 buttons inside, and I want remove this button when people click in a specific part of iframe, not when click in the buttons but when click in a specific part on iframe. When people click in that part, the 3 buttons have to disappear.

This is the code:

```
<div class="frame-container">
<button class="iframe-button">
<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Clicca nello spazio verde per andare avanti->">
</button>
<button class="iframe-button2">
<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="I trucchi sono aggiornati e disponibili GRATIS!">
</button>
<button class="iframe-button3">
<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Registrati adesso per riceverli via EMAIL!">
</button>
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: -120px auto; max-width:;"><br>
<iframe scrolling="no" width="370" height="363" frameborder="0" target="_self" src="test.com" />
</iframe>
</div>
</div>

.iframe-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 32px;
  background-color: #3366cc;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 21px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.iframe-button2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 9px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.iframe-button3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 129px;
  left: 35px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 11px 12.5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: it is the iframe source in a same origin?

Comment: @HannaRose the button is inside the iframe. I have the iFrame loaded with the 3 buttons inside

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port). so to access that buttons in your iframe it must be same origin. thats why i ask it is the iframe source in a same origin?

Answer (score 0):

@HannaRose's question is a crucial one.

There are 2 scenarios:

1. Your iframe is pointing to a site that you have control over
2. Your iframe is pointing to an external site.

**Scenario 1**:
If your iframe is pointing to your own website, then using an iframe may not be the best solution. An iframe is akin to a one-way window - it does not return any data or events when you interact with the website behind the iframe.
It would be better to create 3 buttons on your page to perform the same actions as those of the buttons inside the iframe.

Alternatively, on the page your iframe pointing to - you could hide the buttons when clicked on THAT page.

**Scenario 2**:
If your iframe is pointing to an external website You wont be able to hide the buttons at all. If you could, you would be changing behaviour of another website entirely.
The best you can do is hide the entire iframe when clicked

Comment: I have the Scenario 2, but the button is created myself inside iframe. I only want that the button created disappear after user click in a part of page.

Comment: 1. Your iframe is pointing to a site that you have control over 
2. Your iframe is pointing to an external site.
that was i mean, same origin or not.

Comment: if you are on scenario 2, please read about CORS policy.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS